# Determine if element is a text node using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a jQuery element, how can I determine if the sibling on the right is a text node and not another element? In PHP, you would compare the `nodeType` to `#text` - what's the equivalent in this case?

```
window.jQuery('body').find('a').each(function (i) {


    if(window.jQuery(this).next() == '?'){

    }


});
```

I am trying to work out what I can put in the condition part.

### Update

```
    if(window.jQuery(this).next().length != 0){

        alert(window.jQuery(this).next().get(0).nodeType);  

        if(window.jQuery(this).next().get(0).nodeType == 3){

            alert('right has text');

        }
```

For some reason, all my tests keep returning a 1 rather than a 3 to indicate text nodes!

Comment: check this, may be, dont know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Comment: The accepted answer to this question can be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`next()` only returns elements, so you can't use it to traverse text nodes. You could instead use the DOM `nextSibling` property and check its `nodeType` property:

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kD9qs/

Code:

```
window.jQuery('body').find('a').each(function (i) {
    var nextNode = this.nextSibling;
    if (nextNode && nextNode.nodeType == 3) {
        alert("Next sibling is a text node with text " + nextNode.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: beat me while i was writing exactly the same +1. it took me longer because i was reading jQuery source

Answer (score 2):

as the comment:

check this [**nodeType**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)  and see if helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this, but nodes keep returning as 1 rather than 3 to indicate a text node! I have updated question with what I have so far.